# GWT - ScrollPanel in TabLayoutPanel not working properly if not selected

Tags: gwt, tabs, scrollbar

I have a UI setup where I have a `TabLayoutPanel`, each tab corresponding to a panel, wrapped inside a `ScrollPanel`. Basically this is a chat program, with users able to post messages which will appear in the panels; this means that messages can appear in tabs which aren't currently focused.

Now what I wanted to do (simplified for here) is to have the `ScrollPanel` scroll to the bottom whenever a message arrives, basically to keep the newest message always in view. This works fine in the selected tab, but there's a problem in the tabs that aren't.

Basically, when the amount of messages in the tab gets enough that the scrollbar is needed, it doesn't seem to register until the tab is selected. I can call `getVerticalScrollPosition()` and it will return 0, even though I know there's way more there than would fit; and if I switch to the tab, the scrollbar is resting at the top. If at this point I switch away again, it will work from this point, so the problem is when it goes from not showing the scrollbar to showing it, which doesn't seem to register until the tab is selected.

Does anyone have a suggestion for getting around this behavior? I've tried simply setting the scrollbars to always display, but that didn't help at all.

Answer (score 0):

Not 100% sure but I guess the problem is that `display:none` of the hidden tab might be the reason why `getVerticalScrollPosition()` returns 0.
As a workaround you could add a [SelectionHandler](http://www.gwtproject.org/javadoc/latest/com/google/gwt/user/client/ui/TabLayoutPanel.html#addSelectionHandler%28com.google.gwt.event.logical.shared.SelectionHandler%29) and call `getVerticalScrollPosition()` in that method whenever you switch to the tab with the `ScrollPanel`